# how to check whether an ipset was hooked up to iptables

Tags: iptables, command, firewall, ipset, ip6tables

My iptables output looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set sshd src

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

How can i check to see if this "sshd" set was already hooked up to iptables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-C` flag in `iptables` to check if a set exists:

```
sudo iptables -C INPUT -m set --match-set sshd src -j DROP
```

Return code is > 0 if the set does not exist.

Comment: this looks like what i am looking for, however the syntax seems to be: sudo iptables -C INPUT -m set --match-set sshd src -j DROP and a return code of 2 signifying that the set doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

The *ipset* has a reference counter built-in. So whenever it's referenced by *iptables*, its references counter gets increased. As far as I know, only *ipset*'s meta set `list:set` and *iptables* reference an *ipset*. If you're not using `list:set` or not altering it, you can query directly *ipset* (with `ipset list`) to know if it was referenced by *iptables*.

Example:

```
# ipset create sshd hash:ip
# ipset list
Name: sshd
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 88
References: 0
Number of entries: 0
Members:

# iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set sshd src -j DROP

# ipset list sshd
Name: sshd
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 88
References: 1
Number of entries: 0
Members:
```

The reference count increased. Adding a new `iptables` command using this set will increase it to 2. etc.

The XML format output might help scripts with the right tools. Eg:

```
# references=$(ipset -terse -output xml list | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/ipsets/ipset[@name="sshd"]/header/references')
# echo $references
2
```